# Why my HTTP status code is returning 403?

Tags: python-3.x, api, get, http-status-code-403

I am learning to work with Python API's. However, I am having a problem.

I am trying to make a URL with string formatting like the following,
`b = "https://maze.coda.io/maze/{id}/check?x={x}&y={y}".format(id = idd, x =str(width_a), y = str(height_a))`
and then using `requests.get` to request an object. I am passing the URL that I made in this GET request. Here I have saved some values in `width_a`, `height_a` and `id` variable. But every time I am getting an HTTP status code 403, but I am expecting it to be 200. I am importing requests and the beginning of my code. I am using Python 3.8. Can someone please give me some suggestion regarding what I can do now? Is the process that I made the URL, wrong?

Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you understand what HTTP status code 403 means (it's explained in the description of the tag you added to the question)?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set headers on your GET request.

Comment: Yes, I understood that my request is legal but I am trying to understand what I should do to fix it. Thank you